# Transposing data frames

Tags: r, reshape2, tidyr

Happy Weekends.

I've been trying to replicate the results from this [blog post](http://blog.yhathq.com/posts/currency-portfolio-optimization-using-scienceops.html) in R. I am looking for a method of transposing the data without using `t`, preferably using `tidyr` or `reshape`. In example below, `metadata` is obtained by transposing `data`.

```
metadata <- data.frame(colnames(data), t(data[1:4, ]) )
colnames(metadata) <- t(metadata[1,])
metadata <- metadata[-1,]
metadata$Multiplier <- as.numeric(metadata$Multiplier)
```

Though it achieves what I want, I find it little unskillful. Is there any efficient workflow to transpose the data frame?

**data**

```
data <- data.frame(
  Series.Description = c("Unit:", "Multiplier:", "Currency:", "Unique Identifier: "),
  Nominal.Broad.Dollar.Index. = c("Index:_1997_Jan_100", "1", NA, "H10/H10/JRXWTFB_N.M"),
  Nominal.Major.Currencies.Dollar.Index. = c("Index:_1973_Mar_100", "1", NA, "H10/H10/JRXWTFN_N.M"),
  Nominal.Other.Important.Trading.Partners.Dollar.Index. = c("Index:_1997_Jan_100", "1", NA, "H10/H10/JRXWTFO_N.M"),
  AUSTRALIA....SPOT.EXCHANGE.RATE..US..AUSTRALIAN...RECIPROCAL.OF.RXI_N.M.AL. = c("Currency:_Per_AUD", "1", "USD", "H10/H10/RXI$US_N.M.AL"),
  SPOT.EXCHANGE.RATE...EURO.AREA. = c("Currency:_Per_EUR", "1", "USD", "H10/H10/RXI$US_N.M.EU"),
  NEW.ZEALAND....SPOT.EXCHANGE.RATE..US..NZ...RECIPROCAL.OF.RXI_N.M.NZ.. = c("Currency:_Per_NZD", "1", "USD", "H10/H10/RXI$US_N.M.NZ"),
  United.Kingdom....Spot.Exchange.Rate..US..Pound.Sterling.Reciprocal.of.rxi_n.m.uk = c("Currency:_Per_GBP", "0.01", "USD", "H10/H10/RXI$US_N.M.UK"),
  BRAZIL....SPOT.EXCHANGE.RATE..REAIS.US.. = c("Currency:_Per_USD", "1", "BRL", "H10/H10/RXI_N.M.BZ"),
  CANADA....SPOT.EXCHANGE.RATE..CANADIAN...US.. = c("Currency:_Per_USD", "1", "CAD", "H10/H10/RXI_N.M.CA"),
  CHINA....SPOT.EXCHANGE.RATE..YUAN.US.. = c("Currency:_Per_USD", "1", "CNY", "H10/H10/RXI_N.M.CH"),
  DENMARK....SPOT.EXCHANGE.RATE..KRONER.US.. = c("Currency:_Per_USD", "1", "DKK", "H10/H10/RXI_N.M.DN"),
  HONG.KONG....SPOT.EXCHANGE.RATE..HK..US.. = c("Currency:_Per_USD", "1", "HKD", "H10/H10/RXI_N.M.HK"),
  INDIA....SPOT.EXCHANGE.RATE..RUPEES.US. = c("Currency:_Per_USD", "1", "INR", "H10/H10/RXI_N.M.IN"),
  JAPAN....SPOT.EXCHANGE.RATE..YEA.US.. = c("Currency:_Per_USD", "1", "JPY", "H10/H10/RXI_N.M.JA"),
  KOREA....SPOT.EXCHANGE.RATE..WON.US.. = c("Currency:_Per_USD", "1", "KRW", "H10/H10/RXI_N.M.KO"),
  Malaysia...Spot.Exchange.Rate..Ringgit.US.. = c("Currency:_Per_USD", "1", "MYR", "H10/H10/RXI_N.M.MA"),
  MEXICO....SPOT.EXCHANGE.RATE..PESOS.US.. = c("Currency:_Per_USD", "1", "MXN", "H10/H10/RXI_N.M.MX"),
  NORWAY....SPOT.EXCHANGE.RATE..KRONER.US.. = c("Currency:_Per_USD", "1", "NOK", "H10/H10/RXI_N.M.NO"),
  SWEDEN....SPOT.EXCHANGE.RATE..KRONOR.US.. = c("Currency:_Per_USD", "1", "SEK", "H10/H10/RXI_N.M.SD"),
  SOUTH.AFRICA....SPOT.EXCHANGE.RATE..RAND.US.. = c("Currency:_Per_USD", "1", "ZAR", "H10/H10/RXI_N.M.SF"),
  Singapore...SPOT.EXCHANGE.RATE..SINGAPORE...US.. = c("Currency:_Per_USD", "1", "SGD", "H10/H10/RXI_N.M.SI"),
  SRI.LANKA....SPOT.EXCHANGE.RATE..RUPEES.US.. = c("Currency:_Per_USD", "1", "LKR", "H10/H10/RXI_N.M.SL"),
  SWITZERLAND....SPOT.EXCHANGE.RATE..FRANCS.US.. = c("Currency:_Per_USD", "1", "CHF", "H10/H10/RXI_N.M.SZ"),
  TAIWAN....SPOT.EXCHANGE.RATE..NT..US.. = c("Currency:_Per_USD", "1", "TWD", "H10/H10/RXI_N.M.TA"),
  THAILAND....SPOT.EXCHANGE.RATE....THAILAND. = c("Currency:_Per_USD", "1", "THB", "H10/H10/RXI_N.M.TH"),
  VENEZUELA....SPOT.EXCHANGE.RATE..BOLIVARES.US.. = c("Currency:_Per_USD", "1", "VEB", "H10/H10/RXI_N.M.VE")
)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
# Omitted data <- structure part ...
```

Here is something that replicates what's in the main answer, but more generically (e.g., works where `Series.Description` is not the first column of the result) and using the newer `pivot_wider`/`pivot_longer` verbs.

```
df_transpose <- function(df) {
  
  df %>% 
    tidyr::pivot_longer(-1) %>%
    tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = 1, values_from = value)

}

df_transpose(data)
#> # A tibble: 26 x 5
#>    name                   `Unit:`    `Multiplier:` `Currency:` `Unique Identifi…
#>    <chr>                  <chr>      <chr>         <chr>       <chr>            
#>  1 Nominal.Broad.Dollar.… Index:_19… 1             <NA>        H10/H10/JRXWTFB_…
#>  2 Nominal.Major.Currenc… Index:_19… 1             <NA>        H10/H10/JRXWTFN_…
#>  3 Nominal.Other.Importa… Index:_19… 1             <NA>        H10/H10/JRXWTFO_…
#>  4 AUSTRALIA....SPOT.EXC… Currency:… 1             USD         H10/H10/RXI$US_N…
#>  5 SPOT.EXCHANGE.RATE...… Currency:… 1             USD         H10/H10/RXI$US_N…
#>  6 NEW.ZEALAND....SPOT.E… Currency:… 1             USD         H10/H10/RXI$US_N…
#>  7 United.Kingdom....Spo… Currency:… 0.01          USD         H10/H10/RXI$US_N…
#>  8 BRAZIL....SPOT.EXCHAN… Currency:… 1             BRL         H10/H10/RXI_N.M.…
#>  9 CANADA....SPOT.EXCHAN… Currency:… 1             CAD         H10/H10/RXI_N.M.…
#> 10 CHINA....SPOT.EXCHANG… Currency:… 1             CNY         H10/H10/RXI_N.M.…
#> # … with 16 more rows
```

But note that (like the answer above) the name of the first column is lost. The following retains this (as, I guess does the `spread_(names(data)[1], "val")` approach proposed by @jbkunst above).

```r
df_transpose <- function(df) {
  
  first_name <- colnames(df)[1]
  
  temp <-
    df %>% 
    tidyr::pivot_longer(-1) %>%
    tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = 1, values_from = value)
  
  colnames(temp)[1] <- first_name
  temp
}

df_transpose(data)
#> # A tibble: 26 x 5
#>    Series.Description       `Unit:`   `Multiplier:` `Currency:` `Unique Identif…
#>    <chr>                    <chr>     <chr>         <chr>       <chr>           
#>  1 Nominal.Broad.Dollar.In… Index:_1… 1             <NA>        H10/H10/JRXWTFB…
#>  2 Nominal.Major.Currencie… Index:_1… 1             <NA>        H10/H10/JRXWTFN…
#>  3 Nominal.Other.Important… Index:_1… 1             <NA>        H10/H10/JRXWTFO…
#>  4 AUSTRALIA....SPOT.EXCHA… Currency… 1             USD         H10/H10/RXI$US_…
#>  5 SPOT.EXCHANGE.RATE...EU… Currency… 1             USD         H10/H10/RXI$US_…
#>  6 NEW.ZEALAND....SPOT.EXC… Currency… 1             USD         H10/H10/RXI$US_…
#>  7 United.Kingdom....Spot.… Currency… 0.01          USD         H10/H10/RXI$US_…
#>  8 BRAZIL....SPOT.EXCHANGE… Currency… 1             BRL         H10/H10/RXI_N.M…
#>  9 CANADA....SPOT.EXCHANGE… Currency… 1             CAD         H10/H10/RXI_N.M…
#> 10 CHINA....SPOT.EXCHANGE.… Currency… 1             CNY         H10/H10/RXI_N.M…
#> # … with 16 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 41):

Using `tidyr`, you `gather` all the columns except the first, and then you `spread` the gathered columns.

Try:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>%
  gather(var, val, 2:ncol(data)) %>%
  spread(Series.Description, val)
```

Comment: Absolutely beautiful, @AnandaMahto. Thank you so much. I never get my head around inner workings of `tidyr`. This is my study material for the weekend.

Comment: I love this solution. A slightly more generic way is replace  `spread(Series.Description, val)` by `spread_(names(data)[1], "val")`

Comment: Very elegant. I'm about 3 months into an intensive R learning experience, having started from pretty much zero knowledge. (And I'm not a developer by training or profession.)

Would someone explain to me why gather/spread is a better solution than melt/dcast in this situation? It'd be really helpful in my learning.

 I know this is a better Q for blog.rstudio, but this question is here, not there!

Comment: @Steve `gather`/`spread` is not a *better* solution than `melt`/`dcast`; it's just a *different* solution that fits in with a different grammar of data manipulation. You would note, for instance, that `dcast` also allows for aggregation while reshaping, while `spread` would require already aggregated data. If you're just reshaping the data, then it's down to a matter of preference, I'd say.

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 Great solution! Any way to preserve the row order of the first column when it's spread as column names? I have a column of dates in my first column and when that gets spread to the new columns it gets converted to character and ordered alphabetically.

Comment: @pentandrous, why don't you just convert to factor, with the levels in the correct order, and then `spread`? For example, compare the `spread` results for "df1" and "df2" here: `df1 <- df2 <- data.frame(key = c(1, 2, 2), var = letters[c(1, 3, 2)], val = c(10, 20, 30), stringsAsFactors = FALSE); df2$var <- factor(df2$var, c("c", "b", "a")); spread(df1, var, val); spread(df2, var, val)`.

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 Thanks, that works. I didn't want to type the levels so used `pull(df, first_col)` to set the order. I also got it to work by keeping the dates in the first column in `%Y-%m-%d` format.

Comment: `gather` and `spread` is deprecated. Instead us `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider`.