# transpose data matrix while keeping values numeric

Tags: r, matrix, transpose

I have a set of data like so

```
  GSM482075 GSM482076 GSM482077 GSM482078 GSM482079 GSM482080 GSM482081 GSM482082
1   8.79703   8.04291   7.53674   9.94527   8.38775   8.02375   11.1607   10.5481
2   5.66556   6.42794   6.62527   6.19131   5.34138   5.69543    5.9252   5.55675
```

I want to transpose and turn the columns into rows and rows into columns but when I use t() it converts the numeric values into strings.

```
 1         2        
GSM482075 "8.79703" "5.66556"
GSM482076 "8.04291" "6.42794"
GSM482077 "7.53674" "6.62527"
GSM482078 "9.94527" "6.19131"
GSM482079 "8.38775" "5.34138"
GSM482080 "8.02375" "5.69543"
GSM482081 "11.1607" "5.9252" 
GSM482082 "10.5481" "5.55675"
```

I've looked around but I haven't found a straightforward way to keep the numbers numeric. I was thinking about stripping out the labels but I haven't seen any answers on how to do that except people telling others not to. Any suggestions? thanks

EDIT: Results of str(geomatrixsub) 1st object shown

```
 'data.frame':  2 obs. of  8 variables:
$ GSM482075: chr  "8.79703" "5.66556"
$ GSM482076: chr  "8.04291" "6.42794"
$ GSM482077: chr  "7.53674" "6.62527"
$ GSM482078: chr  "9.94527" "6.19131"
$ GSM482079: chr  "8.38775" "5.34138"
$ GSM482080: chr  "8.02375" "5.69543"
$ GSM482081: chr  "11.1607" "5.9252"
$ GSM482082: chr  "10.5481" "5.55675"
```

using 
    t(geomatrixsub[1:2,]  )

```
      1         2        
GSM482075 "8.79703" "5.66556"
GSM482076 "8.04291" "6.42794"
GSM482077 "7.53674" "6.62527"
GSM482078 "9.94527" "6.19131"
GSM482079 "8.38775" "5.34138"
GSM482080 "8.02375" "5.69543"
GSM482081 "11.1607" "5.9252" 
GSM482082 "10.5481" "5.55675"
```

Comment: is your data a data.frame? try `t(sapply(dat, as.numeric))`

Comment: results of `str(your_data)` , please?

Comment: Your values almost certainly are not numeric to begin with, despite looking like they are.  My guess is they are `factor`.  Post the result of `str(x)` where `x` is your data.frame

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28917076/transposing-data-frames

Comment: Your data isn't numeric! So why by transposing it it will magically become numeric?

Comment: Yeah, I guess it started off as nonnumeric so LegalizeIt's solution seems to have worked. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I know there are several solutions around here with `reshape2` and `tidyr` functions. I've tried a base R solution. Here is it:

```
 t(dat[1:2, ])
                 1       2
GSM482075  8.79703 5.66556
GSM482076  8.04291 6.42794
GSM482077  7.53674 6.62527
GSM482078  9.94527 6.19131
GSM482079  8.38775 5.34138
GSM482080  8.02375 5.69543
GSM482081 11.16070 5.92520
GSM482082 10.54810 5.55675
```

I have used data provided, read in R with this with this code that has a data frame of numeric but with matrixes I think it should work too:

```
dat <- read.table(text = " GSM482075 GSM482076 GSM482077 GSM482078 GSM482079 GSM482080 GSM482081 GSM482082
1   8.79703   8.04291   7.53674   9.94527   8.38775   8.02375   11.1607   10.5481
                  2   5.66556   6.42794   6.62527   6.19131   5.34138   5.69543    5.9252   5.55675")
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is an old post, but I had the same problem and I found another way to do it.

```
dat <- read.table(text = " GSM482075 GSM482076 GSM482077 GSM482078 GSM482079 GSM482080 GSM482081 GSM482082
1   8.79703   8.04291   7.53674   9.94527   8.38775   8.02375   11.1607   10.5481
                  2   5.66556   6.42794   6.62527   6.19131   5.34138   5.69543    5.9252   5.55675")

dat_t = as.data.frame(x = t(dat), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


> dat_t
                 1       2
GSM482075  8.79703 5.66556
GSM482076  8.04291 6.42794
GSM482077  7.53674 6.62527
GSM482078  9.94527 6.19131
GSM482079  8.38775 5.34138
GSM482080  8.02375 5.69543
GSM482081 11.16070 5.92520
GSM482082 10.54810 5.55675
```

The original source is here: https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-transpose-data-frame-and-retain-variable-data-types/45843

Comment: The OP says the starting data structure is a 'data matrix'. Your answer--while useful--returns a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution could be this one:

```
data[] <- lapply(data, type.convert, as.is = TRUE)
```

Example based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52910321/13997761):

```
sampleDF <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,"string"), b = c(1,2,3,4), c= c(5,6,7,8), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
out <- as.data.frame(t(sampleDF), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
out[] <- lapply(out, type.convert, as.is = TRUE)
```