# R transposing numeric data.frame results in character variables

Tags: r, dataframe, character, numeric, transpose

I've got a data.frame which contains a character variable and multiple numeric variables, something like this:

```
sampleDF <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,"String"), b = c(1,2,3,4), c= c(5,6,7,8), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Which looks like this:

```
       a b c
1      1 1 5
2      2 2 6
3      3 3 7
4 String 4 8
```

I'd like to transpose this data.frame and get it to look like this:

```
  V1 V2 V3     V4
1  1  2  3 String
2  1  2  3      4
3  5  6  7      8
```

I tried

```
c<-t(sampleDF)
```

as well as

```
d<-transpose(sampleDF)
```

but both these methods result in V1, V2 and V3 now being of characer type despite only having numeric values.

I know that this has already been asked multiple times. However, I haven't found a suitable answer for why in this case V1, V2 and V3 are also being converted to character.

Is there any way how ensure that these column stay numeric?

Thanks a lot any apologies already for the duplicate nature of this question.

EDIT:

```
as.data.frame(t(sampleDF)
```

Does not solve the problem:

```
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ V1: Factor w/ 2 levels "1","5": 1 1 2
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "a" "b" "c"
 $ V2: Factor w/ 2 levels "2","6": 1 1 2
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "a" "b" "c"
 $ V3: Factor w/ 2 levels "3","7": 1 1 2
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "a" "b" "c"
 $ V4: Factor w/ 3 levels "4","8","String": 3 1 2
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "a" "b" "c"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After transposing it, convert the columns to `numeric` with `type.convert`

```
out <- as.data.frame(t(sampleDF), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
out[] <- lapply(out, type.convert, as.is = TRUE)
row.names(out) <- NULL
out
#   V1 V2 V3     V4
#1  1  2  3 String
#2  1  2  3      4
#3  5  6  7      8

str(out)
#'data.frame':  3 obs. of  4 variables: 
#  $ V1: int  1 1 5
#  $ V2: int  2 2 6
#  $ V3: int  3 3 7    
#  $ V4: chr  "String" "4" "8"
```

---

Or `rbind` the first column converted to respective 'types' with the transposed other columns

```
rbind(lapply(sampleDF[,1], type.convert, as.is = TRUE), 
               as.data.frame(t(sampleDF[2:3])))
```

NOTE:  The first method would be more efficient

---

Or another approach would be to `paste` the values together in each column and then read it again

```
read.table(text=paste(sapply(sampleDF, paste, collapse=" "), 
     collapse="\n"), header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#  V1 V2 V3     V4
#1  1  2  3 String
#2  1  2  3      4
#3  5  6  7      8
```

---

Or we can convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.matrix' which changes the `character` elements to `NA`, use the `is.na` to find the index of elements that are NA for replacing with the original string values

```
m1 <- data.matrix(sampleDF)
out <- as.data.frame(t(m1))
out[is.na(out)] <- sampleDF[is.na(m1)]
```

---

Or another option is `type_convert` from `readr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
sampleDF %>% 
     t %>%
     as_data_frame %>%
     type_convert
# A tibble: 3 x 4
#     V1    V2    V3 V4    
#   <int> <int> <int> <chr> 
#1     1     2     3 String
#2     1     2     3 4     
#3     5     6     7 8
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm now using the first approach and it works perfectly. 
Still don't understand though what's happening behind the scenes in t() such that numeric columns get converted to character ..

Comment: @rajomato  With `t`, you get a `matrix` and matrix can have only a single type.  So, if there are any value that is `character`, it converts the whole set to `character` types.  With `as.data.frame`, and `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`, we have have data.frame structure with each unit being a column.  Then, we can use this unit (column) to convert it to their respective class with `type.convert` by inferring the values in it

Comment: Makes perfectly sense now! Thanks a lot @akrun.