# How can I use tribble to transpose a numeric tibble?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I try to follow the `tidyverse` approach and I extracted numerical data as tibble. As a matrix I would just transpose the data. There seems to be the function `tribble` in `tibble` for this but I can not make it work.

How can I set the column names in the call? I can't see it from the help.

```
library(tidyverse)
iris = as_data_frame(iris)
iris = select(iris,-Species)

tribble(iris)
```

gives the error

> Error: no column names detected in 'tribble()' call

PS: I think there should be an easier way than doing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28917076/transposing-data-frames).

Comment: Judging by the examples in the help file `?tribble`, I don't think this function has anything to do with transposing `tibble` objects (or any other type of existing object).

Comment: @nrussell [here](https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/08/29/tibble-1-2-0/) they say that tribble stands for transpose tibble ... and I guess that's why there is an "r" for tibble transpose .. tribble ...

Comment: @nrussell any other idea how to transpose a numerical tibble without making it a matrix first?

Comment: Regardless of the origins of the name, if the function were intended to be used as `transposed_tibble_object <- tribble(tibble_object)` I'm pretty sure there would be at least one example of that in the help file. As for your question, calling `t(tibble_object)` will dispatch `t.data.frame`. Does that not produce the output you are looking for?

Comment: @nrussell yes I can just use `t()` ... I just thought that there were something more convenient. I think I have to tall `as_data_frame` again to be back at a tibble.

Comment: Maybe just define `t.tbl_df <- function(x) { as_data_frame(t.data.frame(x)) }` as a work around.

Answer (score 2):

`tribble` is used to create a `tibble`, but enter the information row-wise (thus, t**r**ibble) instead of column-wise. 
These two are identical:

```
a <- tribble(
  ~colA, ~colB, 
  "a",   1,
  "b",   2, 
  "c",   3
)

b <- tibble(colA = c("a", "b", "c"), colB = c(1:3))
```

`is.tibble(a)` and `is.tibble(b)` both produce `TRUE`.

As suggested in the comments by nrussell, you can transpose your tibble with `t()`

```
library(tidyverse)    
iris_t <- iris %>% t %>% as_tibble
```