# Reshaping tidyr data

Tags: r, reshape, tidyr

I want to reshape a very simple dataframe and can't find the way to do that

I tried this solution: [Transposing data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28917076/transposing-data-frames/28917212#28917212)
and all related solutions, with no luck

I have a tidy dataframe who looks like this:

```
    df<-rbind(c('a','x1'),c('a','x2'),c('a','x3'),
    c('b','x6'),c('b','x7'))
    colnames(df)<-c('var','val')
```

And tried

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  gather(var, val, 2:ncol(df)) %>%
  spread_(names(data)[1], "val")
```

I want a dataframe that looks like:

```
a   x1   x2   x3  
b   x6   x7   NA
```

But I get this error

> ```
> Error: Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys
> ```

Comment: FYI, your `df` is a matrix not a data frame

Comment: @Sotos: I tried to simplify here the actual dataframe I have. Sorry for my ignorance, but convert the data frame I have to a matrix would simplify the resolution of the problem?

Comment: No, it needs to be a data.frame. No problem though. I got what you were asking. I was just looking for a duplicate target as this looks like a question that has been asked before :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We need a group by sequence after converting to `data.frame` (the OP's example is a `matrix`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
   as.data.frame %>%
   group_by(var) %>% 
   mutate(rn = str_c("col", row_number()))  %>% 
   spread(rn, val)
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   var [2]
#  var   col1  col2  col3 
#  <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct>
#1 a     x1    x2    x3   
#2 b     x6    x7    <NA>
```

Comment: The reason for my downvote here is because I think your answering dupes actually creates a lot of noise in the site thus not helping. A clear dupe was added (OP said he has a data frame but put here matrix for simplicity-or so he thought) and your reopening is not justified in my oppinion, hence the downvote. The other link you share, not my downvotes. Thanks.

Comment: It is a matrix, and it had to go through couple of steps, and note that your sequence creation is for the row index in that dupe and note for the column

Comment: Ok. Your opinion. Lets agree to disagree :) Have a nice day